# Single word for "decided but possibly unknown"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example :

> You are dealt a card, face down, at a casino. Before you turn it over to look at it, the card you have been
>   dealt is _______ [decided, but unknown].

Comment: constant ------

Comment: @GregLee Saying the card you have been dealt is "constant" doesn't sound right to me. I thought about "fixed" or "immutable" but these don't really have the meaning I'm looking for.

Comment: Does "rigged" fit the definition you are looking for?

Comment: Newton's law of universal gravitation is F = G (m1*m2)/r^2, where G is the gravitational constant. It's fixed, but I don't off-hand know what it is.

Comment: @GregLee It depends on which units you use. With a suitable choice of units you can make it have whichever numerical value you like. So it's not really fixed. Anyway that's not the point. Saying "the card you've been dealt is constant" doesn't sound right.

Comment: Sadly, I can't find a dictionary licensing a metaphorical broadening of _face-down_. Perhaps OED does.

Comment: I gave G in Newton's Law as an example of the sense of *constant* that I had in mind.

Comment: It's just that it is known to someone (the dealer) but not known to you. There's nothing "decided" about it. When you posted the question, you thought someone knows the answer, but you don't.

Comment: If the cards are shuffled face down (as I thought was implied) then the dealer doesn't know which card it is before dealing it.

Answer (score 1):

*Concealed* would fit your criteria. For example, the dealer concealed the cards by placing them, face down, on the table. Other words include, *unascertained*, *hidden*, *undisclosed*, *undetermined*, *undiscovered*, etc...

Comment: These all mean "unknown" rather than "possibly unknown." The distinction is important for my intended usage.

Comment: @Randy Randerson 'undisclosed' certainly means 'known to some but not to all', but does not have the 'determined but [as yet] unknown to all' sense.

Comment: See the edit. It doesn't have my desired meaning, even though what I said was incorrect.

Comment: From seeing your edit, I think you're looking for the word *undiscovered*. For example, 'the card on the table remains undiscovered".

Comment: In the new example, it would be: "your card is possibly undiscovered" (decided being implied). It's not really what I'm looking for. Thanks though

Comment: You could try illusive, mysterious, untold or a similar word while implying that it is already determined. For instance, 'The kind of card the dealer dealt was mysterious and shrouded in secrecy'.

Answer (score 1):

> You are dealt a card, face down, at a casino. Before you turn it over
>   to look at it, the card you have been dealt is ***unrevealed***.

M-W:

> **[unrevealed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrevealed)**
>   *adjective*
>   : **not made known or opened up to view** : not revealed
>
> In a livestream event today, Blizzard revealed the final handful of
>   unrevealed cards from its upcoming Hearthstone expansion, The
>   Witchwood, which launches April 12 with 135 new cards.